# Django: static folder for template's assets

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-2.0

I'm learning `Django 2.0`
I have a ready-made template, that contains all assets in `assets` folder.
All references in template starts from `assets/...`, and I'm gonna keep it: all links should looks like `{% static 'assets/...' %}`
My Django app has following structure:

```
myapp
├───manage.py
└───mysite
    └───static/mysite/static/assets # some mess here?
    └───templates/mysite/index.html
```

Inside `index.html` I'm using `{% load static %}`,
In `settings` I have just

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

but framework can't find path to assets. What I'm doing wrong?

---

**UPD**

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

Comment: Can you provide some traceback?

Comment: @Shift'NTab Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css, 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' could not be found

Comment: Please provide more detail to your question, add the template and complete code of how you are linking those static files

Comment: @Shift'NTab see update, there is no any details

Comment: @Shift'NTab I guess that problem with `static` folder structure and settings.

Comment: Yeah, try to move your assets folder to the first level folder `static/` your structure should be looks like this `myapp/mysite/static/assets`

Comment: @Shift'NTab this is correct, please make your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use static file like.

> CSS
>
> JavaScript
>
> Images

On Templates Use

{℅ load staticfiles %}

Answer (score 1):

```
 └───static/mysite/static/assets  - You should to change this,**like bellow**

myapp
└───Assets
├───manage.py
└───mysite
    └───mysite # your project files
    └───templates/index.html
```

**and also :**
in your setting.py like this :

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
    ]
```

**and also :** you need to change setting.py file 'DIRS': ['templates'],
or 'DIRS': ['myapp/templates']